# Passing vector by reference, but alterations won't stick c++

Tags: c++, vector, reference, scope

```
void RemoveGreenEffect::processImage(vector<Point>& points)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
    {
        points[i].setGreen(0);
    }
}
```

This function properly brings in the vector and makes the changes locally. It does not, however, keep the changes when the program goes back to main. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please? In case it helps, here is the calling function from main.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ppm.getRows(); ++i)
{
    my_effect->processImage(picture.getPicture()[i]); 
}
```

my_effect is a base class pointer that is pointing to derived object RemoveGreenEffect. getPicture() is a vector of vectors of Point objects so getPicture()[i] is a vector of Point classes. The goal is to remove all green values pixels in a picture one row at a time, but again, the change is only working locally.

Edit, here is the getPicture()

```
vector<vector<Point>> PointFormatPicture::getPicture()
{
return _picture;
}
```

and here is what _picture is

```
vector<vector<Point>> _picture;
```

Comment: Show some more code. What's going on in picture?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `getPicture()`?

Comment: `getPicture` returns a copy of `_picture`, so when you pass that on to `processImage`, it will not affect `_picture`. The compiler should actually flag an error, unless you made your `operator[]` function return a const reference when called on a non-const object.

Comment: Thanks allot, this makes so much sense. Yea its strange that the compiler didn't give an error given that I am using visual studio. Do you know if there's a conventional way to name a class member function that returns a reference like you are suggesting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to return by reference:

```
vector<vector<Point>>& PointFormatPicture::getPicture()
{
   return _picture;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense. Is there a conventional way to name a function for this purpose? A getter doesn't seem like the right way to go about it, and a setter usually doesn't return a value... so i'm not sure what to call it!

Comment: @user3269643: Regarding this function you can have a const version and a non-const version. You might want to name them differently. You can also just name it PointFormatPicture::picture(). There are several examples of this. maybe the most common ones are begin() and end() which exist in both const and non-const versions.